# How to Hide Form

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to hide the main form in vb.net? I want to make it so users press a button and the form disappears. Like make it so the program is still running but there is no window open.
I tried

```
   Me.Hide()
```

But it does not work. Is it possible to do what I am describing?

Comment: What will your application be doing while its hidden and how will you know when it should quit?

Comment: Call Me.Hide() in the button's Click event handler.  This is a bit too obvious, be sure to pick up an introductory book about Winforms programming in your local library.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? is there an error message, does it remain visible, does it quit ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your main form is called, but try this:

```
MainForm.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about making a process run in the background? Or are you thinking of the Hide method? You can hide forms using Form.Hide. You can check this link as to how to get a program to run in the background.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59527-make-a-program-to-run-in-the-background/

Answer (score 0):

You can hide form with `<form>.Hide()`, but let user choice hide or not that form.

Comment: His question is regarding the MAIN form.  If the startup form is hidden, the application automatically closes (if you are using the application framework, that is).

Comment: He can adjust the behavior of that in Project settings. Provided that this is the only (last) form, you can in Application select shutdown-mode. Changing this means he need to perform shutdown on the program manually.

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware Changing the shutdown mode to "When last form closes" doesn't really help, though, since they want to close all the forms and have it still keep running, right?

Comment: Crap.. I was sure I saw a not shutdown option once. Need glasses. Thanks Steven

Comment: I guess I was wrong.  I just tested it and hiding the main form does not cause the application to close.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Hide() only hides form from taskbar, not closing, but `.Close()` closes form